# Shortening a transfer function in matlab?

Tags: matlab

How could I prune or shorten a transfer function in Matlab?
For example I could shorten s, (s-20) and (s+300.8). But how in Matlab?

```
533.4 s (s+300.8) (s-20) (s+3.948)
  ----------------------------------
      s (s+20) (s-20) (s+300.8)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it!
minreal() is the answer.

Comment: Glad you found the answer, I was just going to edit my answer to include that. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Symbolic Math Toolbox, you can use [simplify](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/simplify.html):

```
syms s;
simplify((533.4 * s * (s + 300.8) * (s - 20) * (s + 3.948)) / (s * (s + 20) * (s - 20) * (s + 300.8)))
```

ans =

(2667*(s + 987/250))/(5*(s + 20))